# mysql2 does not log the query with aws-xray-sdk and aws-xray-sdk-mysql

Tags: node.js, mysql2, aws-xray

After following the reference links to trace mysql query

https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/275

https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/6

I have tried to log mysql2 logs but it does not work with aws-xray-sdk and aws-xray-sdk-node npm packages.

I know that aws-xray works well with mysql but it does not work and trace with mysql2.

Following is my code of database connection.

```
const mysql2 = require("mysql2");

const awsXRay = require("aws-xray-sdk");
const captureMySQL = require('aws-xray-sdk-mysql');
const mysql = captureMySQL(mysql2);  

module.exports.getConnection = async (client, service) => {
  const poolConfig = {
    host: mysqlHost,
    port: mysqlPort,
    user: mysqlUser,
    password: mysqlPass,
    database: mysqlDb,
    multipleStatements: true
  };
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(poolConfig);
  connection.connect();

  // create promise to use await
  connection.query = util.promisify(connection.query);
  return connection;
};
```

I have tried to logged the queries but it does not work anyway.

Thank you for to put some light on this issue.

Comment: Hello! I work on the X-Ray SDK team. I know you referenced issues, would you please open a new issue yourself on [the AWS X-Ray node.js SDK repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node) with this question and your [X-Ray produced debug logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-configuration.html#xray-sdk-nodejs-configuration-logging) so we can leverage the community and help answer there? Add the issue link here too so people can find it later :)

Comment: @nathaniel Ruiz thank you for your kind reply. I have resolved an issue but would you mind if you will give your openion about the way I have followed to logs. I will post an answer soon.